# Gulp: Compile SASS to CSS in the same folder

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm trying to set up a modular workflow where, when running `gulp`, it will compile SASS files in a folder to CSS. Those new CSS files will be stored in the same folder.

For example, here's my current folder structure:

```
theme
   - modules
      - hero
         - hero.html
         - hero.scss
```

Here is my 'gulpfile.js':

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task( 'sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('modules/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('modules/**/*.css'))
});
```

However, when running `gulp sass`, this is what my folder structure looks like:

```
theme
   - **
      - *.css
         - hero
            - hero.css
   - modules
      - hero
         - hero.html
         - hero.scss
```

Whereas what I'm after is:

```
theme
   - modules
      - hero
         - hero.html
         - hero.scss
         - hero.css (hero.css to appear here after running gulp)
```

Am I far off?

Comment: According to their example, you could try `gulp.dest('modules')` See https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/dest#sourcemaps  `dest` does not mention supporting wildcards

Comment: @Freddy please check my answer and let me know if any problem

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your answers. I've selected the best answer as I did because it allowed me to use `gulp watch` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to return `.css` file where `.scss` file exist. Here is the `gulpfile.js` code.

```
'use strict';
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var paths = {
    styles: {
        src: 'modules/**/*.scss',
        dest: 'modules'
    }
}
function scss() {
    return gulp.src(paths.styles.src)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }))
        .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer()]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest));
}
exports.scss = scss
function watch() {

    scss()

    gulp.watch(paths.styles.src, scss);
}
exports.watch = watch
```

`package.json` file need `devDependencies` and `browserlist`. it will be like this.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.7.4",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-postcss": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 71 version"
  ],
```

use `$ gulp watch` running your task.

Your folder structure like this

```
Themes
    modules
        hero
            hero.html
            hero.scss
        header
            header.html
            header.scss
        footer
            footer.html
            footer.scss
    package.json
    gulpfile.js
```

It will return

```
Themes
    modules
        hero
            hero.html
            hero.css
            hero.scss
        header
            header.html
            header.css
            header.scss
        footer
            footer.html
            footer.css
            footer.scss
    package.json
    gulpfile.js
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

`gulp.dest()` only wants a path, it will then append the current file path to it. And `sass()` will already have changed the extension to css so that shouldn't be a problem either. So in your case it should work like this.

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('modules/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('modules/'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`gulp.src` tells the Gulp task what files to use for the task,

while `gulp.dest` tells Gulp where to output the files once the task is completed.

So in your case it should work like this

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task( 'sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('modules/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('modules/**'))
});
```